Is there any issue if I put vias too densely?
I am designing my PCB and the image shown is a MOSFET. I have a question if I put the vias too densely (they are filled and capped), is there any drawbacks? They are thermal vias, suppose they are dissipate heat to other layer, what I am thinking is adding more vias and increase the thermal conductivity to other layer, but my concern is will this bring other drawbacks?
Thank you!


I don’t really understand how you want them to be filled and caped vais if you want to solder the mosfet right on top of them

WC_iOS - This is a gentle reminder. You have still not edited your previous question to add the required reference for the source of the schematic image you copied there. FYI this means that previous question currently breaks the site rules, which is not something you want to be seen doing. Please review & follow the advice given on that question. TY

Too much congested vias can create many problems. Dense vias under components, such as MOSFETs, can cause issues during soldering. If thermal vias are placed directly under pads, they can wick solder away from the pad, leading to poor solder joints or even voids. An optimum distance should be maintained. You can see here for more:
https://www.pcbway.com/blog/Engineering_Technical/Via_spacing_on_high_performance_PCBs.html

The OP indicates that the vias are filled and capped so solder wicking should not be an issue.

Yes, my vias are filled and capped. In this case, will this cause any issues?

The following is a list of all the potential issues I can think of:

Most obvious is that the vias act as an obstacle to routing traces on all layers (unless they're blind vias, but using blind vias for thermal purposes would be very strange), and will likewise cut into any planes that are not part of the same net.
Unless mitigated somehow, vias on top of a solder pad will impede soldering--they can wick solder away from the joint. The more vias, the worse the effect. This can be prevented in a handful of ways: plugging the vias with either epoxy or a solid copper slug will remove any chance of solder loss, but costs a lot extra; making the vias so small that they get filled up with copper during the plating step would have a similar effect at less cost, though the extra-small vias may cost extra themselves; or just making sure they're completely tented with soldermask on the opposite side, which is unreliable but costs you nothing.
The added thermal conductivity can itself be a problem for rework, making it harder to remove the chip if it needs to be replaced. This is mostly a concern during prototyping, and less of one on a production design unless you anticipate doing component-level repair on production units.
Due to mechanical manufacturing tolerances, there is a fab-dependent minimum spacing between vias that you do need to respect. Trying to put vias too close together will cause the fab to reject your design. This limits how densely you can pack vias even in the absence of any other concern.
You wouldn't want vias too dense anyway, because (unless filled and capped as mentioned above, which adds cost) while more vias increase the through-board conductivity (both electrical and thermal), they lower the in-plane conductivity because everywhere a via is, in-plane copper isn't. This isn't a significant effect unless you're using way too many vias, but it is something to bear in mind.

Finally, if you've packed vias as densely as you can and you still don't have enough thermal conductivity, you may need to consider a copper slug in the PCB. This is a process some fabs offer, usually at a pretty severe premium and increased lead time, wherein an arbitrarily-shaped section of the substrate is removed entirely and replaced with a slug of solid copper, which is then joined to the PCB copper. This is not a cheap process and not one you should consider unless you've exhausted all other options, including using a thinner PCB or an aluminum-core PCB.
